hwclock - No usable clock interface found
I'm running Linux 6.1 built with yocto 4.2 mickeldore. I'm trying to get my hwclock to match my system clock via the command sudo hwclock -w --verbose
It fails to do so and spits out the following verbose
hwclock from util-linux 2.38.1
System Time: 1729058181.939602
Trying to open: /dev/rtc0
Trying to open: /dev/rtc
Trying to open: /dev/misc/rtc
No usable clock interface found.
hwclock: Cannot access the Hardware Clock via any known method.

None of my /dev/rtc seems to configured and when I do a dmesg doesn't show any rtc enabled.
I checked the device tree and I can see that a DS1336 RTC module is added to the device
    /* DS1337 RTC module */
    rtc@68 {
        status = "okay";
        compatible = "dallas,ds1337";
        reg = <0x68>;
    };

via bitbake -c menuconfig I have enabled DS1337, /dev/rtcN (character devices) and /sys/class/rtc/rtcN (sysfs). With a new kernel loaded nothing seems to be changed.
Going down this rabbit hole I'm unsure how to get my hwclock to be set up properly. I'm under the impression that it's because my /dev/rtc isn't set up properly and it doesn't look like I am able to set it up. Any help on how to debug this further or get my /dev/rtc (which I think should solve this problem) would be appreciated.

Without seeing more of the dts, I'd assume your RTC modules is over I2c? Is your I2C bus enabled and accessible in your system?

"I have enabled DS1337 ..." - What you did is unclear, because the Linux kernel has no such configuration symbol. Therefore the kernel you built probably does not have any device driver for that RTC.

I think there is a typo in your question "I can see that a DS1336 RTC module …". I think you meant DS1337.

Have you enabled the CONFIG_RTC_DRV_DS1307 kernel option? I recommend configuring the modules for the RTC and the I2C controller as built-in y rather than as modules m so that the kernel can read the time early for its log messages before userspace is ready.
